# What is the first fundamental form? In simple terms.

Tags: differential-geometry

How do you explain the meaning, nature and the use of first fundamental form in layman terms or simple terms? How to intuitively think about first fundamental form?

Answer (score 0):

The first fundamental form provides a way of measuring the lengths of curves on a surface.  You can think of it as being related to the dot product.

Comment: It *is* a dot product on the tangent plane of the surface at each point. Dot product gives you more information than just lengths of vectors!